# Knockout custom binding handler: valueAccessor is not a function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to use a custom binding handler I've written for a text input field that has an input mask on it. However, when I am trying to use this, I get an error in my console:

`Uncaught TypeError: valueAccessor(...) is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (knockout.bindings.ts:11)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5206)
    at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:5014)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.js:8201)
    at Object.simulate (jquery.js:8260)
    at HTMLDocument.handler (jquery.js:8319)`

This is my binding handler:

```
import ko from 'knockout';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Inputmask from 'inputmask';
import moment from 'moment';

ko.bindingHandlers.dateInputMask = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        $(element).on('focusout change', function () {
            console.log(allBindings);
            if (element.inputmask.isComplete()) {
                let time = moment(element.value, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
                valueAccessor()(time); //error thrown from this line
            } else {
                valueAccessor()(null);
            }
        });

        Inputmask('date').mask(element);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        let value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        let text = moment(value).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
        element.value = text;
    }
}
```

My page model (stripped of irrelevant fields):

```
import ko from 'knockout';
import moment from 'moment';

export class EventModel {
    startDate: KnockoutObservable<moment.Moment>;
    endDate: KnockoutObservable<moment.Moment>;

    constructor(params: any) {
        this.startDate = ko.observable<moment.Moment>(moment());
        this.endDate = ko.observable<moment.Moment>(params.endDate || moment());
    }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label">Startdatum</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input class="form-control date" data-bind="dateInputMask: startDate" />
    </div>
</div>
```

A screen of the console when putting a breakpoint on the `init` line to see the value of `valueAccessor`:
[image: valueAccessor]

A screenshot of the model's json rendered in the HTML (there are some fields in there that I stripped from the model code above):
[image: json]
Any help would be greatly appreciated. From what I can tell, these errors usually mean the passed `valueAccessor` is not an observable, but I don't think that's the case here.

Comment: Whats the result of `console.log(valueAccessor);` in either the `init` or `update`?

Comment: I'd also be curious to see the result of `ko.toJSON($root);` from within your HTML. This is a very coming technique for debugging knockout view models/apps.

Comment: I have added the screenshots @pimbrouwers

Comment: thx for posting that. To me it looks like you have a race condition happening here. To be clear that we're not looking at some side effect, can you please comment out all the internals (except the `console.log`) of both the `init` and `update` funcitons?

Comment: That doesn't seem to give too much information sadly: https://i.imgur.com/UFAZmZv.png

Comment: I think this tells quite a story! That being, something causing the value to mutate as denoted by the difference in the init/update log. Unless you're manually triggering that by interacting with the UI?

Comment: In case you're interested, I figured it out. It was not a problem with any of the code posted here or the binding handler itself for that matter. In my "root" model which contained the `EventModel`, I was trying to pass parameters to the constructors of `EventModel` class like so: `this.eventModel = ko.observable<EventModel>(params)`. Well, when I looked back at the code today I realized that doesn't actually instantiate the `EventModel` with the params I said, but it initializes an observable object with those params. So the `valueAccessor` for `startDate` was undefined, if that makes sense.

Comment: WOW!!!! Tough one to find. Was nice debugging with you either way. Tot ziens!